# How can I shutdown ReactiveMongo 0.11.14 without a bunch of dead letter messages?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I'm using ReactiveMongo 0.11.14 with Play 2.5.8.  When I try to shut down reactivemongo, I get a bunch of akka messages about dead letters.  The lost messages all seem to relate directly to closing down. (They are all of class ChannelClosed or ChannelDisconnected.)

How do I properly shut down reactivemongo to avoid these annoying messages?

Here's the way I'm trying to do it now:

```
for (connection <- reactiveMongoApi.driver.connections) {
  //close them sequentially just to be extra safe
  Await.ready(connection.askClose()(5.seconds), 5.seconds)
}
reactiveMongoApi.driver.close(5.seconds)
```

Here's two examples of the dead-letter messages I get:

> [INFO] [10/06/2016 15:14:07.387] [reactivemongo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://reactivemongo/user/Connection-2] Message [reactivemongo.core.actors.ChannelClosed] from Actor[akka://reactivemongo/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://reactivemongo/user/Connection-2#1711870153] was not delivered. [9] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
>
> [INFO] [10/06/2016 15:14:07.387] [reactivemongo-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://reactivemongo/user/Connection-2] Message [reactivemongo.core.actors.ChannelDisconnected] from Actor[akka://reactivemongo/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://reactivemongo/user/Connection-2#1711870153] was not delivered. [10] dead letters encountered, no more dead letters will be logged. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

I've tried closing the connections after the driver, skipping connection close() altogether, and initiating a shutdown via driver.system.terminate() instead of driver.close().

Comment: First you should not close manually the Play plugin which is released by app lifecycle. Then, as indicated by the logger level, unless you have issue/anomaly, these akka INFO messages don't indicate anything wrong.